# 実行ボタン（緑色の旗）がプログラム読み込み時点でOnになっており、Offに切り替えできません

Tags: aibo-visual-programming

aiboビジュアルプログラミング画面の右上にある、実行ボタン（緑色の旗マーク）と停止ボタン（赤い丸）についての質問です。

事前に作成したプロジェクトを読み込んだ時に、実行ボタンが自動的に動作状態（ボタンにピンク色の背景がついた状態）になり、停止ボタンを押しても停止できないことがあります。

SONY作成のサンプルプロジェクトを読み込んだ場合、[レベル2-1] ピンクボールを蹴る、[レベル2-2] 肉球でワン、[レベル2-3] 3回まわってワン、[レベル3-1] いっしょに遊ぼう、を読み込んだときにこの状態になります。

読み込み時に実行ボタンを動作させない、または停止する方法はありますでしょうか。
PCブラウザはGoogle Chrome ver.85、スマホはAndroid 10です。

補足：
実行ボタンがOnのままの状態だと、自動的にaibo本体の呼び出しを試みるようで、aibo本体をスリープにした状態でプログラミングをしているときに「isVoiceCommand : aibo と通信できませんでした」のエラーが頻繁に出てしまいます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

「aiboのイベント」にある 「"aibo" が "＊＊＊" と言われたとき」のブロックは
画面の右側に置いてあると常に実行状態となり、停止することはできません。
そのため、このブロックを含むプロジェクトでは実行ボタンは動作状態のままとなり、
停止ボタンを押しても停止できません。

> aibo本体をスリープにした状態でプログラミングをしているときに、「isVoiceCommand : aibo と通信できませんでした」のエラーが頻繁に出てしまいます。

上述のように、「"aibo" が "＊＊＊" と言われたとき」のブロックは常に実行状態となるため、
aiboと通信ができない場合にエラーが出続けてしまいます。
このエラーメッセージが出ている状態でも、そのほかの操作はお使いいただけます。
aibo が起動しておらずエラーが気になる場合は、「"aibo" が "＊＊＊" と言われたとき」のブロックだけを削除してお使いください。

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム